# two tableviews in ViewController

Tags: swift, tableview

I dragged two tableviews int the ViewController and then dragged one tablecell into each tableview. [Here is my storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1rJr.png).

App crashes for some reason. Here is the code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewControllerwithTable: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var RFTable: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var IMProdTable: UITableView!

var RFArray = ["one", "two"]
var IMProdArray = ["three", "four"]

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

self.RFTable.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
self.IMProdTable.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell2")
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
if tableView == RFTable {
    return self.RFArray.count;
} else {
    return self.IMProdArray.count;
}
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let Cell:UITableViewCell =  self.RFTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")! as     UITableViewCell
    Cell.textLabel!.text = String(self.RFArray[indexPath.row])
    return Cell

    let Cell2:UITableViewCell = self.IMProdTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell2")! as UITableViewCell
    Cell2.textLabel!.text = String(self.IMProdArray[indexPath.row])
    return Cell2

}
}
```

Comment: If your app crashes, there's likely an error message indicating *why* it crashed. Look for that error message. You might even post it here in an edit to your question if the message doesn't fully explain the crash.

Comment: Did you set the view controller as the `UITableViewDelegate` and as the `UITableViewDataSource` ?

Comment: @kangarooChris In the "cellForRowAtIndexPath", it looks like cell2 never has a chance to return.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your responses. This is what I get as an error message:

2016-02-07 18:23:51.865 equ[5675:470470] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] instantiated view controller with identifier "UIViewController-JKJ-t1-Txm" from storyboard "Main", but didn't get a UITableView.'

Comment: @MikeG I only set the UIViewController, NO UITableViewDelegate or UITableViewDataSource. By the way, when I am running the code in a UITableViewController then it works fine , but I want the flexibility of having two tableviews in one screen

Comment: Right, so the reason it works when you run it in a UITableViewController is becuase the delegate and datasource are already setup for you. When you drag your own table view(s) into a UIViewController, you must configure the delegate and datasource yourself, manually

Comment: Voting to close as Typo "resolved in a manner unlikely to be useful to future readers" as per OP self-answer

Comment: @Drew    agree,  not helpful to others, would it be OK to delete the question?

Comment: Maybe wait and think about it and wait for upvotes. Maybe improve self-answer. As of now it might gets deleted by the robot in 9 days. Here is one [reference](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256021)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITableViewDelegata and UITableViewDataSource were not set.